Dictionary updates values without me wanting it to
I am trying to save locations of each selected object into a dictionary and then zero them.
But the dictionary values get updated after I save the values and zero the objects' location.
I just dont understand why and how to get around it. The only thing that worked is to save the location value as a string and then I would have to deconstruct the string back into a vector when trying to restore these locations.
selObjs = bpy.context.selected_objects    
newDict = {}
for object in selObjs:  
    newDict[object] = object.location
    object.location = (0,0,0)

When I run this, it saves the correct location value for the object key into the dictionary, but the moment object.location = (0,0,0) is called, the value gets zeroed inside of the dictionary too.
I just cant make sense of this, the values are not meant to update without me actually updating the dictionary, are they?
Thanks for the help.

Try object.location.copy().

That was it! Lovely and simple. Thank you Martynas

Im not sure why but it would seem that the variable indeed is getting updated even tho it should not. Saving the variables' copy is all that was needed to solve it:
selObjs = bpy.context.selected_objects    
newDict = {}
for object in selObjs:  
    newDict[object] = object.location.copy ()
    object.location = (0,0,0)

Thanks Martynas

"...even tho it should not. " - This is how it works. It's intentionally meant to work like that as far as I can tell and is not a mistake or a bug.  You need to copy the value, not use the location itself. Location of objects gets updated by the API - how else would it work?..

Its good that it works like that but literally all python documentation I checked makes no mention of dictionary values auto update when saving variable into it, cuz as the name suggest, i thought i was saving the VALUE of that variable into it, not the actual variable. There are plenty of cases i think of where the way it works is great, but this was rather confusing. Thank you for your help.
